# Kafka Consumer not reading more than one record in unit tests

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka consumer:

```
consumer.subscribe(statusTopicList);
        try {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords =
                    consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(60));

                System.out.println("SIZE IS: " + consumerRecords());
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String > record : consumerRecords) {

                   System.out.println(“Record is: “ + record.value());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
```

And in my unit tests:

```
 ((MockConsumer<String, String>) consumer)
        .addRecord(new ConsumerRecord<>(
            topic, 1, 0, "test-application1", record1));

    ((MockConsumer<String, String >) consumer)
        .addRecord( new ConsumerRecord<>(
            topic, 1, 0, "test-application2", record2));
```

The size of the consumerRecords is still 1 though I’m adding 2 records. How can I read both the messages in one poll?

My consumer properties are:

```
  private static Consumer<String, SecondaryJoinStatus> createStatusConsumer() {

        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,
                groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put("schema.registry.url",
                schemaRegistryUrl);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,
                “EARLIEST");
        props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", 5242880);

        return new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG` config to poll more records [here](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerConfig.html#MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG)

```
 props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 5);
```

Comment: Hi. That didn’t help. I still see just one record

Comment: so you are saying, it is reading one by one record? or only just one record? @user10751899 and also can you show the `MockConsumer` code